# Videos de youtube con ReyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube

[image]

Como hago esto? que se vayan actualizando solos

Comment: Bienvenido..Emmanuel..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: La respuesta a la pregunta es "SI", simplemente necesitas usar la API o un feed que contenga los ids de videos.

Comment: Que tal Jorgesys, sabes de que manera lo puedo hacer,  o donde encuentro el procedimiento? desconozco realmente como hacerlo

Comment: Hola @EmmanuelCampuzano te sugiero revises este excelente articulo: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/tutorial-para-crear-un-lector-rss-en-android/ realiza el ejemplo para que tengas idea de lo que comento. En realidad tu pregunta es demasiado amplia (ver [ask]) Te aconsejo también que vayas realizando preguntas sobre todo esto por partes y de esta forma te podamos ayudar para que realices tu proyecto! :-)